# Identical particles in infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

I have a question about identical particles in an infinite potential well. 
In Zettili's quantum mechanics textbook, Section 8.5, problem 8.1(c), the Pauli exclusion principle is used to find the ground state.

Now, what I want to do is that, as is used in solved problem 8.5, find the ground state by using 
$$\Psi_{\text{a}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2} \Big[ \psi_{\text{s}}(x_1,x_2) \chi_{\text{a}} +  \psi_{\text{a}}(x_1,x_2) \chi_{\text{s}} \Big], $$
where $\psi_{\text{s}}~(\psi_{\text{a}})$ is a symmetric (anti-symmetric) wave function, 
$$\psi_{\text{s}}(x_1,x_2)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3!}}\Big[ \varphi_{n_1}(x_1) \varphi_{n_2}(x_2)\varphi_{n_3}(x_3) + \cdots \Big],\\
\psi_{\text{a}}(x_1,x_2)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3!}}\Big[ \varphi_{n_1}(x_1) \varphi_{n_2}(x_2) \varphi_{n_3}(x_3) - \cdots \Big].$$
But this causes a trouble; if you guessed wrong and say $(n_1, n_2,n_3)=(1,1,1)$ is the ground state, then $\psi_{\text{a}}=0$ but $\psi_{\text{s}}$ survives. So we get 
$$\Psi_{\text{a}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2} \psi_{\text{s}}(x_1,x_2) \chi_{\text{singlet}} $$
as a ground state wave function. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Before I try and answer this, I just wanted to clarify.  Are we talking about three particles, and there should be $x_1, x_2, x_3$?

Comment: @JamesJohns Yes.

Comment: Help you with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation of your question is a little problematic.  Once you have more than 2 particles (ie 3 or more),  you can no longer split them as a spatial function times a spinor.  So your top line doesn't work out and you can't have a singlet  with 3 spin 1/2 particles, so I think there's some confusion there.  But let's move past that, and take a look at your result.  Your result is correct that you cannot have an antisymmetric wave function with 3 particles in the same quantum states.  The most you can have is two particles in the same spatial functions but with opposite spins.

So, starting over, the ground state for 3 identical fermions MUST be antisymmetric.  I'm inferring that you are talking about fermionic particles because you applied the Pauli Exclusion principle, but I'm not 100% confident based on the rest of the question.  Leave a comment for me if you want me to explain it for bosons as well.  I'll also limit it to a single dimension infinite well.

$$\Psi_a=\frac{c_\alpha}{\sqrt{6}} \begin{vmatrix}
\phi_{n_a}\alpha(1) & \phi_{n_a}\alpha(2) & \phi_{n_a}\alpha(3)\\
\phi_{n_b}\beta(1) & \phi_{n_b}\beta(2) & \phi_{n_b}\beta(3)\\
\phi_{n_c}\alpha(1) &\phi_{n_c}\alpha(2)&\phi_{n_c}\alpha(3)
\end{vmatrix} + 
\frac{c_\beta}{\sqrt{6}} \begin{vmatrix}
\phi_{n_a}\alpha(1) & \phi_{n_a}\alpha(2) & \phi_{n_a}\alpha(3)\\
\phi_{n_b}\beta(1) & \phi_{n_b}\beta(2) & \phi_{n_b}\beta(3)\\
\phi_{n_c}\beta(1) &\phi_{n_c}\beta(2)&\phi_{n_c}\beta(3)
\end{vmatrix}$$

Notationally, $\alpha$ refers to spin up particles, $\beta$ refers to spin down, and $\phi_n=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin{\frac{n\pi x}{L}}$

3 spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles can't be paired up, so we're dealing with what chemists would call an open shell configuration.  Two of the particles can be piled up into the same spatial orbitals with different spins (ie $n_a=1$ and  $n_b=1$, but you still have an electron left over.  As you showed earlier, you can't have $n_c=1$ because your wave function would the equal 0, so the next lowest energy state is $n_c=2$.    Effectively, you're just piling them in two at a time to each spatial orbital, one with each spin.  You eventually have one left over, but we have no reason to assume that it is either spin up or spin down, so let's just write it as a linear combination of both.

Does this line of thinking make sense?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.